# Etsy product scraper pulling off one row of data

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to pull some product data of Etsy.com I am not sure if its because I have the wrong Parent class that I can not pull off the data or another issue. I have tried several classes as the parent class the current one allows me to pull one row off.

Link [Etsy.com](https://www.etsy.com/uk/search?q=phones)

I have waited for the page to load and scroll down the page to ensure it loads correct and not as a lazy loader. However I can still only pull off one row of data.

[image: Results]

My code below normally works for me

```
        Set Html = objIE.document
        Set elements = Html.getElementsByClassName("bg-white display-block pb-xs-2 mt-xs-0") ' parent CLASS
        'FOR LOOP
        For Each element In elements
     
''' Element 1

        If element.getElementsByClassName("js-merch-stash-check-listing  v2-listing-card position-relative flex-xs-none ")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0) Is Nothing Then ' Get CLASS 
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-" 'If Nothing then Hyphen in CELL
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("js-merch-stash-check-listing  v2-listing-card position-relative flex-xs-none ")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href 'Get CLASS 
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = HtmlText 'return value in column
        End If
''' Element 2

        If element.getElementsByClassName("text-gray text-truncate mb-xs-0 text-body")(0) Is Nothing Then ' Get CLASS 
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = "-" 'If Nothing then Hyphen in CELL
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("text-gray text-truncate mb-xs-0 text-body")(0).innerText ' Get CLASS 
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = HtmlText 'return value in column
        End If
''' Element 3
```

**SECOND PARENT CLASS**

I thought I had fixed the problem and did not post my original above question.
With the following parent class below, I was able to pull off one full page 50+ items and column A results. **I have changed nothing since,** however I can not re-produce the same results again. All I get is one row and I can not understand why. I have been trying to fix this for sometime now, but can not work out what the issue is.  The below class worked once and pulled of 50+ results now it only does 1 row, I have cleared all browser caches, and rebooted the PC,

**SECOND PARENT CLASS**

```
Set Html = objIE.document
        Set elements = Html.getElementsByClassName("wt-grid wt-grid--block wt-pl-xs-0 tab-reorder-container") ' parent CLASS
        'FOR LOOP
        For Each element In elements
```

[image: New Results]

I have tried the following Classes, only two pulled some results off as the note state

```
'wt-mt-xs-2 wt-text-black
'col-group pl-xs-0 search-listings-group pr-xs-1
'col-xs-12 pl-xs-1 pl-md-3
'responsive-listing-grid wt-grid wt-grid--block wt-justify-content-flex-start wt-list-unstyled pl-xs-0
'bg-white display-block pb-xs-2 mt-xs-0
'''''wt-grid wt-grid--block wt-pl-xs-0 tab-reorder-container 'Can only do 1 row
'''''wt-grid wt-grid--block wt-pl-xs-0 tab-reorder-container 'I was able to pull of 50+ items now not working
'wt-list-unstyled wt-grid__item-xs-6 wt-grid__item-md-4 wt-grid__item-lg-3 wt-grid__item-xl-3 wt-order-xs-0 wt-order-md-0 wt-order-lg-0 wt-order-xl-0 wt-show-xs wt-show-md wt-show-lg wt-show-xl tab-reorder
'js-merch-stash-check-listing  v2-listing-card position-relative flex-xs-none
```

For each items there is a li Class, see image below for more information

**Questions -**  Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong? (I managed to pull of 50+ results once with the second parent class, how ever this is now only pulling off 1 row, I can not work it out)

```html
<li class="wt-list-unstyled wt-grid__item-xs-6 wt-grid__item-md-4 wt-grid__item-lg-3 wt-grid__item-xl-3 wt-order-xs-0 wt-order-md-0 wt-order-lg-0 wt-order-xl-0 wt-show-xs wt-show-md wt-show-lg wt-show-xl tab-reorder">
  <div class="js-merch-stash-check-listing  v2-listing-card position-relative flex-xs-none " data-palette-listing-id="973170689" data-shop-id="" data-listing-id="973170689" data-behat-listing-card="" data-listing-card-v2="">
    <a class="6dd4c4354676ccda display-inline-block listing-link  logged" data-listing-id="973170689" data-palette-listing-image="" href="https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/973170689/deconstructed-iphone-5-artwork?ga_order=most_relevant&amp;ga_search_type=all&amp;ga_view_type=gallery&amp;ga_search_query=phones&amp;ref=sc_gallery-1-1&amp;plkey=247d3e6c1599979de70c884db995d78e95827f21%3A973170689&amp;frs=1"
      data-display-loc="w.0" data-page-num="1" data-position-num="1" data-logging-key="247d3e6c1599979de70c884db995d78e95827f21:973170689" target="etsy.973170689" title="Deconstructed iPhone 5 artwork">
      <div class="v2-listing-card__img position-relative">
        <div data-listing-card-image="">
          <div class="placeholder placeholder-landscape  ">
            <div class="placeholder-content  ">
              <div class="placeholder vertically-centered-placeholder placeholder-landscape">
                <div class="height-placeholder">
                  <img data-listing-card-listing-image="" src="https://i.etsystatic.com/27880825/c/2250/1788/0/538/il/116587/2961533797/il_340x270.2961533797_r4pc.jpg" class="width-full wt-height-full display-block position-absolute " alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="v2-listing-card__info
">
        <div>
          <h3 class="text-gray text-truncate mb-xs-0 text-body ">
            Deconstructed iPhone 5 artwork
          </h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          <div class="v2-listing-card__shop">
            <p class="text-gray-lighter text-body-smaller display-inline-block" aria-hidden="true"><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="c968b3da8 s0cd3f014">A</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span>
              <span
                class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="c968b3da8 s0cd3f014">d</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="c968b3da8 s0cd3f014"> </span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span>
                <span
                  class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="c968b3da8 s0cd3f014">b</span>
                  <span
                    class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="c968b3da8 s0cd3f014">y</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="c968b3da8 s0cd3f014"> </span>
                    <span
                      class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span><span class="p06299890 c968b3da8">E</span>DissectProjects</p>
            <p class="screen-reader-only">Ad from shop DissectProjects</p>
            <span class="v2-listing-card__rating icon-t-2 display-block">
        </span>
          </div>
          <span class="n-listing-card__price text-gray mt-xs-0 strong display-block
         text-body-larger
        ">
            <span class="currency-symbol">£</span><span class="currency-value">120.00</span>
          <span class="text-body-smaller no-wrap">
             span class="wt-badge wt-badge--small wt-badge--sale-01">
             FREE UK delivery</span>
          </span>
          </span>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div data-favorite-button-wrapper="" class="v2-listing-card__actions z-index-1 position-absolute">
      <button class="inline-overlay-trigger favorite-item-action position-absolute favorite-listing-button p-xs-1 has-hover-state z-index-1 btn-transparent position-right in-search v2-listing-card__favorite" data-ui="favorite-listing-button" data-listing-id="973170689"
        data-accessible-btn-fave="" data-favorite-label="Add to Favourites" data-favorited-label="Remove from Favourites">
            <div data-source="search" data-btn-fave="" data-neu-fave="">
                <span class="favorite-listing-button-icon-container icon-circle-container bg-white icon-group p-xs-1       
                 " data-favorite-icon-container="">
                    <span class="etsy-icon icon-smaller text-gray wt-display-block   
                        " data-not-favorited-icon=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><path d="M12,21C10.349,21,2,14.688,2,9,2,5.579,4.364,3,7.5,3A6.912,6.912,0,0,1,12,5.051,6.953,6.953,0,0,1,16.5,3C19.636,3,22,5.579,22,9,22,14.688,13.651,21,12,21ZM7.5,5C5.472,5,4,6.683,4,9c0,4.108,6.432,9.325,8,10,1.564-.657,8-5.832,8-10,0-2.317-1.472-4-3.5-4-1.979,0-3.7,2.105-3.721,2.127L11.991,8.1,11.216,7.12C11.186,7.083,9.5,5,7.5,5Z"></path></svg></span>
                    <span class="etsy-icon icon-smaller text-red wt-display-none     
                        " data-favorited-icon=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><path d="M16.5,3A6.953,6.953,0,0,0,12,5.051,6.912,6.912,0,0,0,7.5,3C4.364,3,2,5.579,2,9c0,5.688,8.349,12,10,12S22,14.688,22,9C22,5.579,19.636,3,16.5,3Z"></path></svg></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <!--icon font and display:none; elements -->
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon"></span>
            <span class="screen-reader-only default" data-a11y-label="">
                Add to Favourites
            </span>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

[image: Html Image]

**UPDATE FROM SIM CODE**
[image]

I was using this to scroll down the browser.

`objIE.document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 9999 ' Scrolls Down the Browser`

''###################### UPDATE TODAY #######################

I guess the parent class is the `v2-listing-card__info` HOWEVER if I am not mistaken the PRODUCT URL does not fall into this, therefore how do i get that

The results so far, I have not corrected all the other class for the elements yet
[image: results so far]

''####################### UPDATE TODAY 19/3/2021 ######################

A big thanks to `SIM` for the support given, also `Qharr` for his input. I was able to sort this out in the end, thanks guys

RESULTS

[image: Final Results]

As always thanks in advance

Comment: Are you not trying to parse the name and price of the products from that page? The content appears to be static and available in page source. You should go for xmlhttp requests instead of IE which is cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the update SIM, I am using IE as I use the site filters as well so I need the browser to be visible. I know IE is not the best and will be out of date very soon, but for now I am fine with IE, and will look at changing to xmlhttp at  a later date. for NOW I just need the data extracting

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation. First few items are static but the rest are lazy-loaded. However, in that case selenium would be a better choice unless you have already planned on sticking to IE.

Comment: for now, its IE, I do load the page and scroll to the bottom , before it starts extracting. so all items should have loaded  via the lazy loader, I got it working once and now can not seem to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetTitles()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object, startTime As Double
    Dim timeout As Integer, prevlen&, curlen&

    timeout = 5

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.etsy.com/uk/search?q=phones"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With
    
    prevlen = HTML.getElementsByClassName("v2-listing-card").Length

    startTime = Timer

    Do
        HTML.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 99999
        Set posts = HTML.getElementsByClassName("v2-listing-card")
        curlen = posts.Length
        
        If curlen > prevlen Then
            startTime = Timer
            prevlen = curlen
        End If
    Loop While Round(Timer - startTime, 2) <= timeout

    For Each post In posts
        Debug.Print post.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).innerText
        Debug.Print post.getElementsByClassName("listing-link")(0).getAttribute("href")
    Next post
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Btw, if you use

***v2-listing-card__info***

as the container, make sure to use the following line

***post.ParentNode.ParentNode.getElementsByClassName("listing-link")(0).href***

to fetch the product links.

Comment: thanks, SIM, Please see my update above, can you explain what I am doing wrong, I am limited in vba and can not work it out,

Comment: post.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href inside loop

Comment: Check out the edit @Sharid. I've added one line within the loop which will let you fetch the product urls. You can also use what QHarr already suggested.  However, you should make use of this class `v2-listing-card` as a container which holds most of the stuff you are after.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input, I was able to sort this out with your help